# How to write Excel 2010 VBA in Visual studio 2015 Community?

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2015, vba

I have been programming with Excel 2010 VBA for a while but I am a newbie with Visual Studio 2015 Community.

I had installed it when it was announced this year and found the workflow features for developers in regards agile/scrum methodology amazing and wanted to use this for developing Excel 2010 VBA.

I looked on the internet before asking this question and had trouble following these steps which enables you to make an add-in for Excel

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx

the problem appears that references to Office/SharePoint option does not show up in the New Project. Not sure how to get it to work?

Here is a snap showing the section selected and no option for Office/SharePoint
I tried to find it online and doesn't come up on the list.

[image: Visual Studio Selection for Excel]

Thanks and kind regards,
Peter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The community edition should work fine, but you need to install Office Developer Tools too:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/office-tools-vs.aspx

Comment: Thank you Excel Developers. This method works well for me. I was able to use the Visual Studio 2015 Community edition "uninstall feature" to modify my configuration to ensure I have the Office/Sharepoint Tools installed correctly.  Then I was happy to select 2010 excel objects instead of 2013 objects when I followed the steps.

Answer (score 0):

You need (as per the link in the page to which you referred) Visual Studio Professional, Premium or Ultimate in order to develop Office solutions.